# Opening my app when built in app is accessed

Tags: java, android, android-intent

Because I've read that it's bad practice to have your app running at all time, I'm trying to have it start when specific built in apps start.  I believe it has something to do with intent and the following link but I don't know where to start.

http://developer.android.com/training/basics/intents/filters.html

If this is possible can someone post a code snippet to help me out?  I'm wanted my app to start when Media or the camera is accessed and then close when those two apps are closed.

Answer (score 0):

> I'm wanted my app to start when Media or the camera is accessed and then close when those two apps are closed.

That is not possible, sorry.

Comment: Ok thanks.  My app uses about 10 MB of memory when running, in your opinion would this be considered a memory hog app if running at all time?

Comment: @HondaKillrsx: It is not ideal. Your use of CPU, battery, and bandwidth may be worse, depending upon what you are doing. Also, your process will not run forever, as eventually Android will get rid of it, either at the user's request or simply due to old age. And there are thousands of "Media or the camera" apps, including hundreds pre-installed on various Android device models. You might consider asking a separate Stack Overflow question, where you explain what you are trying to accomplish, how you are thinking of solving it, and asking for better solutions or issues with your solution.